# how to spring boot app will read other packages classes for bean creation

Tags: spring-boot

Want to know How to create Bean objects which are not part of the spring main class?

Ex: My SpringApplication main (@SpringBootApplication) class is located in com.app.one package and want to create objects of com.app.two

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at  `@ComponentScan`

Answer (score 0):

add this annotation into your main class.

```java
@ComponentScan("com.app.two")
```